# Create a column in the data to mark the entries Active and Inactive in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a column in my data in MySQL to mark them active and inactive, here the inactive are the duplicate entries and the duplicate will be based in the field name received_on (date) column. The latest date will be marked as active and the others will be inactive.
We also have a unique id field in the data named caseid.

I have used a query max(received_on)< DATE(NOW()) but it only gives me inactive entries.

Comment: Please show sample data, expected outcome (both as tables, no images or links) and the whole query you have tried.

Comment: I don't see your question.

Comment: *The latest date will be marked as active and the others will be inactive.* This makes no sense. The fact that the row is the most recent in a group marks it as active already, and additional column not needed.